# kubectl command timeout on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I setup a cluster from the kubernetes dashboard with 2 nodes in the private network.

I have exposed the port 80 that maps to port 8545 from the container instances. 
So, when I access the external IP I can view my application.

I set up a `kubectl` on my machine and ran the following command

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --zone <my-zone> --project <project name>
```

However, when I run this I get an error

```
$ kubectl get deployments
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 35.194.113.118:443: i/o timeout
```

On the GCP dashboard, I see the following for the cluster

```
Endpoint    
35.194.113.118
```

It also has a view credentials option next to it which has a certificate file and username and password

So, I tried setting it

```
kubectl config set-credentials cluster-admin --username=admin --password=<my password>
```

I tried kubectl command again, however I get the same timeout error.
Can someone help to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I added an authorized network by editing the cluster and selecting `Add Authorized network`.
This seems to have solved the problem.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

Comment: What did u enter for an IP?

Comment: all internet -> 0.0.0.0/0